Is there an R function for identifying every unique pattern a sequence is record as, and returning an example of each please?
I have thousands of three-letter codes separated by either "/", "-" or "*" or a combination of them. I would like to understand how many unique formats they are written in, please. The letters in the code do not matter, just how they are separated, therefore I have just used A's in the example table below:



Column A




AAA/AAA


AAA/AAA/AAA


AAA*AAA-AAA/AAA


AAA/AAA*AAA/AAA


AAA/AAA-AAA


AAA/AAA-AAA/AAA


AAA/AAA-AAA-AAA*AAA-AAA/AAA



All of the entries in column A are in a unique format. For example, AAA/AAA is the same as ABB/ABN, the letters do not matter. However, AHY-AAA is a different format as the three-letter code here is spaced by "-" instead of the earlier "/" examples. The three-letter codes are actually IATA codes, but that does not really matter.
I have tried to define a function to extract patterns but not had any success yet.

Not sure what is meant by "I would like to understand how many unique formats they are written in, please"; please add expected output.

Could you clarify a bit what counts as unique? If you just do stringr::str_remove_all(x, [A-z]) (removing all letters) you will be left with just the separators in each row, which you can then count

All of the entries in column A are in a unique format. For example, AAA/AAA is the same as ABB/ABN, the letters do not matter. However, AHY-AAA is a different format as the three-letter code here is spaced by "-" instead of the earlier "/" examples. The three-letter codes are actually IATA codes, but that does not really matter. Thanks :)

Let's say that your values are stored in a vector called codes. I will also assume that a letter will never be used as a separator. In this case, you can use:
unique(gsub("[A-Za-z]{3}", "#", codes))

This will return all unique formats, where '#' is a representation of the three letter code.
The way that this works is that instead of focusing on the separators, it removes the data from the codes and treats them as the same.
The [A-Za-z]{3} is a regular expression for three letters in a row. If your codes also includes numbers, you can modify this to better reflect the possible codes you have

pretty probable that the letters are DNA or RNA base triplets, which left you with the possible characters GATC and perhaps U.

Is DNA expressed in sequences of 3?

Yes, the codons that codifies proteins, each codon recognizes an amino-acid https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code#Codons

Thanks for this answer. It is for IATA airport codes, eg London Heathrow Airport is LHR
